# Accurate Big-O analysis

Tags: arrays, random, operating-system, big-o

Suppose you need to generate a random permutation of the first N integers. For example, {4, 3,
1, 5, 2} and {3, 1, 4, 2, 5} are legal permutations, but {5, 4, 1, 2, 1} is not, because one number
(1) is duplicated and another (3) is missing. This routine is often used in simulation of
algorithms. We assume the existence of a random number generator, RandInt(i,j), that
generates between i and j with equal probability. Here are three algorithms:

(i) Fill the array A from A[0] to A[N-1] as follows: To fill A[i], generate random
numbers until you get one that is not already in A[0], A[1],…, A[i-1].

(ii) Same as algorithm (i), but keep an extra array called the Used array. When a random
number, Ran, is first put in the array A, set Used[Ran] = true. This means that
when filling A[i] with a random number, you can test in one step to see whether the
random number has been used, instead of the (possibly) i steps in the first algorithm.

(iii) Fill the array such that A[i] = i+1. Then

```
for (i=1; i<n; i++)
swap (A[i], A[RandInt(0,i)]);
```

Give as accurate (Big-O) an analysis as you can of the expected running time of each algorithm.

Anyone can help with this? Cause i just learn this chapter and not quite understand what the question wants..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I:
You have to fill N slots, but as you keep filling you are less likely to get a valid number.
If you have filled M slots, then the chance of getting a valid number is 1-(M/N). In addition, as the list gets longer, you need to iterate over the entire thing. N numbers * O(N) guesses per slot * O(N) checks to see if number is already contained = O(N^3)
(O(N) checks per number because worst case is last number, 1/N chance to get unused one)

II:Now we don't have to iterate over the entire array for each check, so only O(N^2)

III: Swapping takes constant time, and we iterate over the entire array once, so O(N)

I think I did all those correctly, but I easily could have missed something.
Hope this helps.

Comment: so the big-O for part 1 is O(N^3)?

Comment: This is what i get from others. The second algorithm saves a factor of i for each random number, and thus reduces the
time bound to O(N log N) on average. What do you think?

Comment: You need N numbers, and each number takes at most an average of N guesses, which seems like O(N^2) to me. First is O(N^3)

Answer (score 0):

Option 4 : Fill a List / Collection with values from 1 to n, then shuffle the Collection. `O(n) + ~O(n) => O(n)`

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same as his third option? How would you shuffle it differently?

Comment: Yes.. I was still posting my answer when he posted (I guess.. ) :)